# UK Tier 4 Visa UCSIS/Biometrics Help

Tags: uk-visa, study, paperwork, application-status

I posted a similar question in the travel section, however this is super urgent so possibly someone can help me over here...

Basically I had an official appointment at a UCSIS Application Center, which I booked through the UK Visa & Immigration Center for a Tier 4 Visa. I missed the appointment and called only to be told I was not in the system and did not even have an appointment. They advised me to call the UK Visa and Immigration's website, which I did... only to be also told they have no idea what to do. They recommended me to another department and said I'd receive an e-mail within 15 days. Time is of the essence, as I was supposed to be in the UK by the 30th for university, however I believe it is going to be delayed.

Does anyone know as to why this would've happened? Is the UCSIS still processing biometrics? I see there are premium centers available, but for a hefty fee. If I start to book an appointment through them, I want to make sure my previous appointment was voided. I have no idea who to contact anymore as I've contacted both sides with no help.

My only worry is the front cover page of the biometrics, in my visa application I selected the UCSIS location, and have no way of changing it to a premium section now.

Any info in the application that does not match, could cost me being rejected.

If anyone has any further advice as to what I should do next or who to contact, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *I posted a similar question in the travel section* Which one? And if this is only about short time travel, the question is off-topic here. The fact that this is urgent does not change that.

Comment: Did you give the VAC your application reference when you called them? If you missed the appointment the system would obviously show that you no longer have one. It’s possible your application would have been rejected as incomplete following the appointment no-show and the papers are on their way back to you. Which would mean you’d need to reapply.